# Accidentally deleting crucial libraries

Tags: libraries, data-recovery

If you accidentally delete a crucial library folder, such as /usr/lib, how can you recover from that?

Comment: install a second identical system and copy paste from this, or use your backup.

Comment: Either re-install the system or check your backups. Only some high-level package management system would save you (`apt-get`, `yum` or whatever your system is using) and I seriously doubt that some static version is already installed or available.

Comment: `apt-get install --reinstall` if you know what are the packages on Debian systems or on Red Hat based systems: `for file in $(rpm -qla|grep ^/usr/lib/); do echo $(rpm -qf $file); done | uniq | sort > /root/packages.ls` and then `yum reinstall $(cat /root/packages.lst | uniq)`  

THe other way, do as said by @Kiwy

Comment: @nwildner there is probably no possibility of using apt-get or dpkg without /usr/lib

Comment: This guy is a lucky bastard then - http://mcpierce.blogspot.com.br/2012/06/fedora-restoring-accidentally-deleted.html - Well, i stopped to think and yum starts with y, and maybe /usr/lib/yum could be still available after the ^C  ;)

Comment: @Kiwy As long as the file (e.g. glibc) is [open](http://superuser.com/questions/302041/when-does-rm-remove-open-files) (and it will be) you might get lucky.

Comment: @nwildner: and /usr/lib/rpm ... so no rpm as well. So a very very lucky one.

Comment: It greatly depends, how you deleted your data, if you override it, etc. We would need a ton of details before narrowing it down to a couple of answers.

Answer (score 1):

If you delete `/usr/lib`, you will kill your system as very crucial libraries reside in this directory. Like the LibC library which is used by all binaries. So it is unlikely that you will be able to something.
(If you are lucky and interrupted the command with a quick CTRL+C before is comletion, maybe only sub-dirs are deleted and the LibC is still there)

If the system is totally blocked (login impossible, boot fails, ...), let's hope that you have a Live CD of the same distribution and the same version under the hand.

Boot from this CD, mount the filesystem of your hard-disk and copy the `/usr/lib` from the Live system to the one on the hard-disk.

Comment: In fact it is not that bad, as `libc` and many crucial libraries are usually in the `/lib` and/or `/lib64` directories.

Comment: @Ouki: +1 for you, how could it be possible that I forgot this ;-)

Answer (score 0):

`extundelete --restore-all`  when having your file system mounted as read-only. (Be sure you have a ext filesystem.)

! **Be sure** not to install it on the device you want to recover !

Comment: But installing the `extundelete` binary could write things into  `/usr/lib` right?

Comment: as `extundelete` relies on some library I'm not sure this would work. also you're not sure to get 100% of the files you delete specially on a SSD

Comment: @nwildner: Yes, you shouldn't install or write or download anything on your disk, if you want to recover it. But as commented above, there are other ways. (I would give it a try, especially if you have your home partition seperatly. You would need a extra system to install or start extundelete, or just install extundelete and their libs locally.)

Comment: Yeah. And that's why i asked ;). Probably if someone run `yum install extundelete` or `apt-get install extundelete` could overwrite the deleted data on this partition.

Probably the best option to this alternative is to use a totally static binary compiled outside this box. RIP LInux livecd already have this tool installed: http://www.tux.org/pub/people/kent-robotti/looplinux/rip/Changelog

Answer (score -1):

In some cases, you can try to **update or reinstall** the package. For example, if you delete or degrade **libpthread.so** file inside ***/usr/lib***, you can reinstall upper level and container package like ***glibc*** to recover the file. This procedure will be done by dependency library and file check during reinstall or updating.

For example, try:

```
# to recover and take libpthread.so back.
sudo yum install glibc
```